# Having trouble finding the start of a sentence inside string array

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I have a text file from which I read the text in lines. Also from all that text I need to find the longest sentence and find in which line it begins. I have no trouble finding the longest sentence but the problem arises when I need to find where it begins.

**The contents of the text file is:**

> V. M. Putinas
>   Margi sakalai
>   Lydėdami gęstančią žarą vėlai
>   Pakilo į dangų;;, margi sakalai.
>   Paniekinę žemės vylingus sapnus,
>   Padangėje ištiesė,,; savo sparnus.
>   Ir tarė margieji: negrįšim į žemę,
>   Kol josios kalnai ir pakalnės aptemę.

My code:

```
static void Sakiniai (string fv, string skyrikliai)
{
    char[] skyrikliaiSak = { '.', '!', '?' };
    string naujas = "";
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fv, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // Add lines into a string so I can separate them into sentences
        naujas += line;   
    }

    // Separating into sentences
    string[] sakiniai = naujas.Split(skyrikliaiSak); 

    // This method finds the longest sentence
    string ilgiausiasSak = RastiIlgiausiaSakini(sakiniai); 
}
```

From the text file the longest sentence is: `"Margi sakalai Lydėdami gęstančią žarą vėlai Pakilo į dangų;;, margi sakalai"`

How can I find the exact line where the sentence begins?

Comment: side note: you can use `string.Join` to combine all the lines into a single string: `string naujas = string.Join("", lines);`

Comment: You are using a foreach statement, if you want to know the sentence then maybe use a for statement i.e. for(int i; i< lines.count; i++) because this would give you the value for i.

Comment: side note: you can use the  `System.Linq` extension method `Aggregate` to get the longest sentence: `string ilgiausiasSak = sakiniai.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Length > y.Length ? x : y);`

Comment: Question: Doesn't the longest sentence begin with `" Putinas "`? Or is the first line you mentioned not actually a line in the text file?

Answer (score 1):

What about a nested `for` loop? If two sentences are the *same* length, this just finds the *first* one.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fv, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
var terminators = new HashSet<char> { '.', '?', '!' };
var currentLength = 0;
var currentSentence = new StringBuilder();
var maxLength = 0;
var maxLine = default(int?);
var maxSentence = "";

for (var currentLine = 0; currentLine < lines.Count(); currentLine++)
{
    foreach (var character in lines[currentLine])
    {
        if (terminators.Contains(character))
        {
            if (currentLength > maxLength)
            {
                maxLength = currentLength;
                maxLine = currentLine;
                maxSentence = currentSentence.ToString();
            }

            currentLength = 0;
            currentSentence.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            currentLength++;
            currentSentence.Append(character);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the start index of the longest sentence in the whole content

```
int startIdx = naujas.IndexOf(ilgiausiasSak);
```

then loop the lines to find out which line the startIdx falls in

```
int i = 0;
while (i < lines.Length && startIdx >= 0)
{
    startIdx -= lines[i].Length;
    i++;
}
// do stuff with i
```

i is where the longest sentence starts at. e.g. i=2 means it start from the second line

Answer (score 0):

How about

- identify the lines in the text
- split the text into sentences
- split the sentences into sections based on the line breaks (could work also with splitting on words as well if needed)
- verify the sections of the sentence are on consecutive rows

In the end certain sections of the sentence might occur on multiple lines forming other sentences so you need to correctly identify the sentences spreading consecutive rows

```
// define separators for various contexts
var separator = new
{
    Lines = new[] { '\n' },
    Sentences = new[] { '.', '!', '?' },
    Sections = new[] { '\n' },
};

// isolate the lines and their corresponding number
var lines = paragraph
    .Split(separator.Lines, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select((text, number) => new
    {
        Number = number += 1,
        Text = text,
    })
    .ToList();
```

[image]

```
// isolate the sentences with corresponding sections and line numbers
var sentences = paragraph
    .Split(separator.Sentences, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(sentence => sentence.Trim())
    .Select(sentence => new
    {
        Text = sentence,
        Length = sentence.Length,
        Sections = sentence
               .Split(separator.Sections)
               .Select((section, index) => new
               {
                   Index = index,
                   Text = section,
                   Lines = lines
                        .Where(line => line.Text.Contains(section))
                        .Select(line => line.Number)
               })
               .OrderBy(section => section.Index)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Length)
    .ToList();
```

[image]

```
// build the possible combinations of sections within a sentence 
// and filter only those that are on consecutive lines
var results = from sentence in sentences
            let occurences = sentence.Sections
                .Select(p => p.Lines)
                .Cartesian()
                .Where(p => p.Consecutive())
                .SelectMany(p => p)
            select new 
            {
                Text = sentence.Text,
                Length = sentence.Length,
                Lines = occurences,
            };
```

and the end results would look like this

[image: the end results]

where *.Cartesian* and *.Consecutive* are just some helper extension methods over enumerable (see associated [gist](https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/0adfe5844b949f2407f377f520aeb6c0) for the entire source code in linqpad ready format)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T instance)
{
    yield return instance;
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Cartesian<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> instance)
{
    var seed = Enumerable.Empty<T>().Yield();

    return instance.Aggregate(seed, (accumulator, sequence) =>
    {
        var results = from vector in accumulator
                      from item in sequence
                      select vector.Concat(new[]
                      {
                          item
                      });

        return results;
    });
}

public static bool Consecutive(this IEnumerable<int> instance)
{
    var distinct = instance.Distinct().ToList();
    return distinct
        .Zip(distinct.Skip(1), (a, b) => a + 1 == b)
        .All(p => p);
}
```

Comment: Your index keeps track of the **sentence** number, not the **line** number. In your example, the line number of the longest sentence is 8, not 12.

Comment: i've updated my answer to reflect the line number the sentence starts. see the associated gist for the full source code https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/0adfe5844b949f2407f377f520aeb6c0

Comment: I think your gist still has issues. You're finding the line number based on the first word of the sentence - what happens if that word appears multiple times in other sentences?

Comment: i've updated the gist with a broader example covering also scenarios where same words are to be found at the beginning of multiple sentences

Answer (score 0):

**Build an index that solves your problem**.

We can make a straightforward modification of your existing code:

```
var lineOffsets = new List<int>();
lineOffsets.Add(0);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // Add lines into a string so I can separate them into sentences
    naujas += line;   
    lineOffsets.Add(naujas.Length);
}
```

All right; now you have a list of the character offset in your final string corresponding to each line.

You have a substring of the big string. You can use `IndexOf` to find the offset of the substring in the big string.  Then you can search through the list to find the list index of the *last* element that is *smaller or equal* than the offset. That's the line number.

If the list is large, you can binary search it.